# session flash message in cakephp2.x

Tags: php, variables, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, session-variables

i dont have too much experience in the cakephp.
i have set a one session flash message in the controller its syntax is as below

```
$this->Session->setFlash(__('Error :: No product found.', true));

i have two function in Controller 
public function details()
{

}
public function add()
{
//my code goes here
$this->request->data['Product']['togo'] == the path where i have to redirect ( details page)
$this->Session->setFlash(__('updated.', true));
$this->redirect($this->request->data['Product']['togo']);
}

Now in the view folder
i dont have add.ctp file
add function manupulate the data and send them to the details page


details.ctp

Noe in the above page i have write below to display
 <?=$this->Session->flash();  // ?>

Issue 
when i click back or next button in the browser that session message will come on the screen
```

Now this message is properly showing in the view file too. now what is the issue is that
suppose i will click the BACK button of the browser then page is load and that message is shows again. if i will press the NEXT button of the browser then also that session flash message display.
i don't know why i am getting this issue. i have another project in that this functionality is working fine.
please help me to get out of this issue

Thanks in adavance

Comment: Can you give more snapshot of your code?

Answer (score 0):

use redirect

```
$this->redirect(array('controller'=>'Controller1','action'=>'view_name'));
```

OR 
use `hyperlink` at **BACK** button

Comment: in view <? $this->session->flash(); ?>

Comment: finally i found something. just check this link : http://nagarmehul.com/development/cakephp/admin/employees/index/page:1   username and pass both are .admin'.  First login and edit the any user. Now click the back button in the browser and then click the next button of the browser.      Do the same thing for the both browser Chrome and Firefox.  In firefox it works fine but in chrome its not working. so can anyone suggest me how can i solve this browser session flash message issue ?

Comment: which version you used for both browser. In my site its working fine for both browser

Answer (score 0):

**you can try this**

> in Controller Flash message you can define the name of the message what you want such as `saveorerr` and these message write on flash-message it will automatically connect controller flash.
>   and You can also define your custom css with in array in flash message.

```
  return  $this->Session->setFlash('Succesfully updated','default',array('class'=>'alert alert-danger'),'saveorerr');

  <?php echo $this->Session->flash('saveorerr');?>
```

Comment: first of all thanks BUt the issue is that Flash message is working fine.   But when i click on the previous and then next button in the browser it will display again. simply first i click button in the browser and then click on the next button in the browser it will come again so how can i solve this issue. pls help to to get out of this issue

Comment: if you define the the empty flash message `$this->Session->flash()` more then one view `.ctp` file of the same controller the the message show again in the different or  form, So please you can define the different message name of flash.

Comment: i did as you told me but still its now working. still flash message is displays on the site if i will click back and then next button on the browser

Comment: can you show your session code in `controller` and `ctp` file ?